# Erro ao salvar horario php mysql

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável para pegar a data e horário atual mas esta salvando com três horas a mais da atual, alguém já passou por esse problema?

```
$data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s ");
```

Answer (score 3):

O Brasil está no GMT-3, provavelmente  o sistema está configurado para salvar em GMT+0. Pra consertar isso, você precisa demonstrar a estrutura da sua aplicação pra saber quem está sendo o responsável por salvar neste horário. Se você está gerando a data através do PHP, então certamente o problema não é com o MySQL, mas sim com a aplicação. O horário do computador está certo?

Você também pode usar a função [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), que retorna o mesmo formato que o date(), mas utiliza o GTM local para retornar a data.

Answer (score 2):

Tente definir o [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) padrão para ser utilizado nas funções de horário, exemplo *timezone São Paulo*:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Sao_Paulo');
```

ou

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

**[Veja a lista de timezones suportados](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)**